# is it not compulsory to have RSS value with page align

Tags: unix, memory-management, operating-system, page-tables

i was checking memory usage of my application through *time* command. it gives the following output

```
0.01user 0.03system 0:10.05elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 13300maxresident)k
0inputs+256outputs (0major+1368minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

max RSS is 13300 which is not page aligned. he page size on my 64 bit machine (ubuntu) is 4096.
According to my understanding memory allocation/deallocation is based on pages. But RSS figure is not page align. after that I observe through *ps* command same is the case with all processes running in the system.

Does it mean my understanding is not correct that physical memory is allocated/deallocated page wise? Then how memory is allocated and what is memory granularity.

Comment: 13300 is in units of KiB, 1024. So you have 13300*1024, which is a multiple of your pagesize.

Comment: ah I think now i should go to bed :( thanks.

Answer (score 0):

13300 is in units of KiB, 1024. So you have 13300*1024, which is a multiple of your pagesize. – nos